# Drives reading constantly, how do I see a disk's queue? (not the queue length)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, resource-monitor, disk-activity

Here's my problem. Since around two days ago, I noticed that my external HDD LED kept blinking, even though no programs were running. So I checked Task Manager and discovered that something is reading the drive constantly. Stable around 24-26 KB/s. I thought that it might be my antivirus doing some scanning, but the LED kept blinking for more than 6 hours. I noticed that the reads are also happening in all three drives attached to my laptop.

I searched for hours on how to see what's accessing a drive, found lots of methods, and none of them helped. Nothing is accessing any files on the drive. So I want to know what's my drive doing? What is queuing? I can see the queue length in resource monitor (FYI, it's under 0.001 for the external HDD according to the graph), but not the queue itself. Is it possible to see it?

In safe mode though, the LED does not blink constantly. So the culprit mustn't be the system. How would I diagnose further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one method :

- Start the Task Manager
- Go to the Details tab
- Right-click on any column header and choose "Select Columns"
- Select at least the column "I/O reads" and maybe also "I/O writes"
- Click twice on the column to sort by its value in descending order
- Now just watch the processes and identify the ones that are using the disk.
  System processes will have the *User name* of SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE or
  NETWORK SERVICE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an older article on [Microsoft's website](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benp/2010/08/19/how-to-figure-out-which-processes-are-generating-disk-io-in-windows-7/).

In this case you would look for processes that are initiating I/O which would help you identify the culprit on the slow but steady disk access.

You didn't specify what version of Windows, I assume its Windows based on your reference to Task Manager.  If this isn't an exact match this should help get you going in  a direction to identify the process your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I've successfully found the culprit. It is my antivirus after all. After attempting both Hogstrom's and harrymc's answers, I wasn't able to see what's doing this other than my antivirus (or a rogue system service). So I uninstalled my antivirus briefly, and found that the LED stopped blinking.

Wasn't sure why it only started doing this only a few days ago (I've been using it for a long time), but I've sent a ticket to the support team to try and get help to solve this issue.

Anyways, the problem is not fixed yet, but at least the pinpointing part is done. Thanks again Hogstrom and harrymc!